# Upgrade to local ps command to the latest

Tags: osx, ps

I am monitoring the process with us on macos

```
$ ps -f
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501   367   366   0 Sun06AM ttys000    0:00.21 -bash
  501  1814  1812   0 Sun06AM ttys001    0:00.29 -bash
  501 36857  1814   0  6:41PM ttys001    0:00.00 head -n -2
  501 36858  1814   0  6:41PM ttys001    0:00.00 sed 3d
  501  9616  9612   0 Sun10AM ttys002    0:02.09 -bash
  501 36264 36262   0  6:23PM ttys003    0:00.16 -bash
```

when I tried

```
$ ps --forest
ps: illegal option -- -
```

It report illegal option

The manual stats the version if

```
March 20, 2005     BSD
```

When I switch to centos

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# ps --forest
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
16683 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
17853 pts/1    00:00:00  \_ bash
17865 pts/1    00:00:00      \_ bash
17879 pts/1    00:00:00          \_ ps
```

It comes with powerful --forest.

it's version is July 2014

How could I update outdate ps or install a new one?

Comment: Did you try installing `pstree`? Also, you need to start tagging your questions with the correct things.

Comment: got it butpstree shows an enormous messages, could I install it from source code? @Kusalananda

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why are you running macOS since all your questions are about getting it to behave like Linux? Can't you just run Linux instead? I'll look at this issue whenever I get to my office.

Comment: up up voted. but it's very hard to change all the mobile devices which have data in cloud. @Kusalananda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Homebrew on macOS, you may install `pstree` get similar functionality.

In comments you say you've tried this but that it gives too much information.  You should read the `pstree` manual to figure out how to use the tool.  Note that `pstree` is available on Linux as well.

To get the process tree for the current shell process:

```
desktop:~ myself$ pstree -p $$
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 00985 myself /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
   \-+= 00989 myself /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp myself
     \-+= 00990 root login -fp myself
       \-+= 00991 myself -bash
         \-+= 51939 myself pstree -p 991
           \--- 51940 root ps -axwwo user,pid,ppid,pgid,command
```

The Linux `ps` utility is not installable on macOS as far as I know, probably due to the fact that it's making heavy use of the Linux-specific `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: I got your idea and understand why I copy some tools directly from centos to local fails.(I git async the /bin to local days ago)